# How to save csv file data to a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a csv file imported in a data grid view in my window application. Its a 40 columns data with more than 100 records. Now what I want is to save the grid view data to a database.
I have tried bulkinsert but its giving error : Cannot access the destination table
I m not sure how to create a table in such case. I mean do I need to define all the 40 columns ? What if everytime I import the csv file, the column names are different ?

Here are the codes I have been trying:

```
string rowValue="";
string[] cellValue;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
if (System.IO.File.Exists(csvPath.Text))
{
    System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(csvPath.Text);
    // Reading header
    rowValue = streamReader.ReadLine();
    cellValue = rowValue.Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < cellValue.Count(); i++)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.Name = cellValue[i];
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
     }
     // Reading content
     while (streamReader.Peek() != -1)
     {
        rowValue = streamReader.ReadLine();
        cellValue = rowValue.Split(',');
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellValue);
      }
      streamReader.Close();
 }
 else
 {
      MessageBox.Show("Please Select a File!");
 }
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

For saving to database table:

```
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\\tushar\\dbLws.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        con.Open();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbName.Text.Trim()))
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Please supply Table Name");
        }
        SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default);
        sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tbName.Text.Trim();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name, dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name);
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);

        sqlBulkCopy.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Saved successfully");

        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Anyway you needs a some kind of mapping between CSV & Database columns

Answer (score -1):

http://raffidotnetlearner.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-upload-csv-file-data-into.html

Its working perfect please go through steps awesome yar

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.